# trying to connect SQL using node js

Tags: node.js, sql-server-2012

app.get('/', function (req, res) {
    var config = {
        user: 'sa',
        password: '',
        server: 'localhost',
        database: 'TestDB'
    };

```
// connect to your database
sql.connect(config, function (err) {

    if (err) console.log(err);

    // create Request object
    var request = new sql.Request();

    // query to the database and get the records
    request.query('select * from userInfo', function (err, recordset) {

        if (err) console.log(err)

        // send records as a response
        res.send(recordset);

        console.log(recordset);
    });
});
```

});

Getting this error in command prompt

```
{ Error: Failed to connect to localhost:1433 - Could not connect (sequence)
    at Connection.tedious.once.err (D:\Nodejs\UsersCreate\node_modules\mssql\lib\tedious.js:216:17)
    at Object.onceWrapper (events.js:293:19)
    at emitOne (events.js:96:13)
    at Connection.emit (events.js:191:7)
    at Connection.socketError (D:\Nodejs\UsersCreate\node_modules\tedious\lib\connection.js:875:14)
    at D:\Nodejs\UsersCreate\node_modules\tedious\lib\connection.js:740:25
    at SequentialConnectionStrategy.connect (D:\Nodejs\UsersCreate\node_modules\tedious\lib\connector.js:153:9)
    at Socket.onError (D:\Nodejs\UsersCreate\node_modules\tedious\lib\connector.js:169:16)
    at emitOne (events.js:96:13)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:191:7)
  code: 'ESOCKET',
  originalError:
   { ConnectionError: Failed to connect to localhost:1433 - Could not connect (sequence)
       at ConnectionError (D:\Nodejs\UsersCreate\node_modules\tedious\lib\errors.js:12:12)
       at Connection.socketError (D:\Nodejs\UsersCreate\node_modules\tedious\lib\connection.js:875:30)
       at D:\Nodejs\UsersCreate\node_modules\tedious\lib\connection.js:740:25
       at SequentialConnectionStrategy.connect (D:\Nodejs\UsersCreate\node_modules\tedious\lib\connector.js:153:9)
       at Socket.onError (D:\Nodejs\UsersCreate\node_modules\tedious\lib\connector.js:169:16)
       at emitOne (events.js:96:13)
       at Socket.emit (events.js:191:7)
       at emitErrorNT (net.js:1284:8)
       at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:80:11)
       at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:104:9)
     message: 'Failed to connect to localhost:1433 - Could not connect (sequence)',
     code: 'ESOCKET' },
  name: 'ConnectionError' }
{ ConnectionError: Connection is closed.
    at Request._query (D:\Nodejs\UsersCreate\node_modules\mssql\lib\base.js:1299:37)
    at Request._query (D:\Nodejs\UsersCreate\node_modules\mssql\lib\tedious.js:497:11)
    at Request.query (D:\Nodejs\UsersCreate\node_modules\mssql\lib\base.js:1242:12)
    at D:\Nodejs\UsersCreate\app.js:118:17
    at _poolCreate.then.catch.err (D:\Nodejs\UsersCreate\node_modules\mssql\lib\base.js:269:7)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:109:7) code: 'ECONNCLOSED', name: 'ConnectionError' }
undefined
```

Please help me on this error and need navigation to rectify this error

Comment: Where is SQL Server/network library error? Check SQL Server error log, if there is no error at all it means that your connection string is wrog. If there is the error "login failed for user sa" update your question with that error (show us the next row with error cause)

Comment: I got it, it was only because of TCP\IP was disabled and after enabled it was connected to database